# Python: Creating a dataframe of closing stock prices from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I've scoured the interwebs, but can't seem to figure out how to do what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
from datetime import datetime

asset_list = ['AAPL', 'FB', 'NFLX']
start = datetime(2018, 11, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 11, 25)

data = pdr.DataReader(asset_list, 'iex', start, end)
```

This returns a dictionary with keys represented by each stock, columns for "open", "high", "low", "close", and "volume" and rows for each date between start and end dates.

```
print(data)

{'AAPL':               open     high     low   close    volume
date                                                 
2018-11-21  179.73  180.270  176.55  176.78  31124210
2018-11-23  174.94  176.595  172.10  172.29  23623972, 'FB':                                   
open    high       low   close    volume
date                                                  
2018-11-21  134.40  137.19  134.1300  134.82  25469735
2018-11-23  133.65  134.50  131.2551  131.73  11886128, 'NFLX':                   
open    high     low   close    volume
date                                                
2018-11-21  274.42  275.34  261.51  262.13  11023037
2018-11-23  260.11  265.50  256.84  258.82   5245123}
```

And

```
type(data)
dict
```

What I want is a data frame that has columns represented each stock and rows that represent the close price for those stocks for each date between start and end dates.

Something like this:

```
Date        stock1      stock2      stock3      stock4
11/25/2013  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice
11/26/2013  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice
11/27/2013  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice  ClosePrice
etc...
```

Sorry if this isn't being asked correctly, but this is my very first post and I'm new to all of this so thanks in advance for the community's patience and help!

***EDIT***

Using Kevin Fang's answer below (which is exactly what I want), and making sure I have the latest panda reader installed, I have the following input/output:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
from datetime import datetime

asset_list = ['AAPL', 'FB', 'NFLX']
start = datetime(2018, 11, 1)
end = datetime(2018, 11, 25)

data = pdr.DataReader(asset_list, 'iex', start, end)
d = data['close']
d.head(5)
```

---

```
1y

--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
-
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call     
last)
<ipython-input-10-d8026b04c184> in <module>()
  4 
  5 data = pdr.DataReader(asset_list, 'iex', start, end)
----> 6 d = data['close']
  7 d.head(5)

KeyError: 'close'
```

If anyone has any idea why it's not working for me I'd be very grateful for the help!

Comment: I don't see the dictionary :-).

Comment: Sorry Joshua, I just edited with the output of what I currently have! Its type is  showing as 'dict'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post an example of your dataframes my best bet is on `pd.concat`

First, set the index of your dataframes to `Date`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

Then slice and concatenate the dataframes:

```
merged = pd.concat([df1['close'], df2['close'], ...], axis=1)
```

Then recover the date as a column, and rename other columns:

```
merged = merged.reset_index()
merged = merged.rename(columns={'before':'after'})
```

If you could give a minimal example I can provide some detailed results.

EDIT:

I've tried your code and it is not giving me a dictionary but a huge dataframe, so after I did `d = data['close']` then I got a dataframe the same as your desired output:

```
# after your codes
d = data['close']
d.head(5)
Out[22]: 
Symbols        AAPL     FB     NFLX    TSLA
date                                       
2013-11-27  71.5811  46.49  51.7842  126.94
2013-11-29  72.9066  47.01  52.2571  127.28
2013-12-02  72.2720  47.06  51.9885  124.17
2013-12-03  74.2507  46.73  51.8485  144.70
2013-12-04  74.0774  48.62  50.8957  138.95

d.reset_index().head(5)
Out[23]: 
Symbols        date     AAPL     FB     NFLX    TSLA
0        2013-11-27  71.5811  46.49  51.7842  126.94
1        2013-11-29  72.9066  47.01  52.2571  127.28
2        2013-12-02  72.2720  47.06  51.9885  124.17
3        2013-12-03  74.2507  46.73  51.8485  144.70
4        2013-12-04  74.0774  48.62  50.8957  138.95
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! When I try that i get the following:

KeyError: 'close'. The type is definitely showing as "dict". Any ideas why you might be getting a dataframe where I'm getting a dictionary?

Comment: @we2beans maybe update your `pandas-datareader`? I have no clue, mine installed just now

Comment: Thanks Kevin Fang. Super appreciative for all the help! I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: @we2beans I've read through source code of pandas-datareader and when inputs of symbols is a list, it is support to do the following at the end: `result = pd.concat(result).unstack(level=0)`
            `result.columns.names = ['Attributes', 'Symbols']`
            `return result` so I'm pretty sure it will return a dataframe other than a dict

Comment: I'm in the middle of installing on another laptop to see if the same thing happens. Hopefully it'll work on the other one since I've inputted the code exactly as above. :-/

Comment: You won't believe it, but the install on the different laptop worked! Thanks so much for all the help Kevin! I'd buy you a beer if I could!!